# IONIC keeps saying the plugin is not installed

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

To be more specific, the plugins are: **@ionic-native/estimate-beacons** and **@ionic-native/ibeacon**. I have followed all the steps and also add the plugin into my app's module. This also happens once to my @ionic-native/ble.

Here are the console logs: 
[image]

and:
[image]

Am I missing any step? I'm getting very frustrated since the project is stuck right at the beginning.

P/s: I'm using IONIC and Cordova ' newest version. I follow the docs to install the plugin:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-estimote
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/estimote-beacons
```

then

> After installing a plugin’s package, add it to your app’s NgModule.

After that, I DO see the plugin shows up in the **plugins** folder. All finished but everytime got asked to install the plugin!!!

Comment: Try to update SDK and ionic on the system that should be helpful

Comment: Hi, I already made an update on ionic and cordova through node. But everything is unchanged.

Comment: Android SDK is up-to-date?

Comment: Yes, it is freshly installed.

Comment: Oh and btw, the plugins that I want DO show up in the plugins folder. But still, I can't use i.